# Azure App Service: specifying docker run port on container side

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, splash-screen, azure-web-app-service

I want to use [scrapinghub/splash](https://hub.docker.com/r/scrapinghub/splash) container on Azure App Service (Web App for Containers) on Linux.
But docker run command on deploy randomly changes the binding port of container side (see the log below, port 8961 is automatically assigned. this number varies every deploy)

> 2020-01-21 08:56:47.494 INFO  - docker run -d -p **8961:8050** --name b2scraper-splash_3_d89ce1f2 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=8050 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=b2scraper-splash -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=8050 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=b2scraper-splash.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=5446f93a2cbcb25300f091395c54ce738773ce47489c2818322ffabbc23e3413 scrapinghub/splash:latest python3 /app/bin/splash --proxy-profiles-path /etc/splash/proxy-profiles --js-profiles-path /etc/splash/js-profiles --filters-path /etc/splash/filters --lua-package-path "/etc/splash/lua_modules/?.lua" --disable-private-mode --port 8050

Changing host port binding is possible using WEBSITES_PORT, but seems no way to change container side.
**Is there way to fix container-side port binding like `-p 8050:80` or `-p 8050:443` of `docker run` command?**

e.g. Using the container on Azure Container Instances is possible, without changing service port 8050.

Answer (score 2):

--publish in the docker run command creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

For the command: docker run -d -p 8961:8050 imagename, TCP port 8050 in the container is mapped to 8961 on the Docker Host. On App Services, this docker run command cannot be changed. The container port (8050 in this case) can be set to a specific value using WEBSITES_PORT application setting.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn´t work. you get 443 as port with HTTPS.
Neither EXPOSE XXXX, nor WEBSITES_PORT or PORT as configuration parameters...
You do see "docker run -d -p 8961:8050" in the logs, but it doesn´t matter to Azure when it comes to exposing the app...